# How to send every email you send additonally to yourself in bcc using outloook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, bcc

Every email I send from my account in Outlook should be additionally send to my account in BCC. I am able to apply a rule on every email I send and to add my account in CC, but not BCC.

Is there any way to this in Outlook? It's quite easy using Thunderbird.

I am aware of this question:

[Entourage 2008 or Outlook 2003/7 - always BCC a specific address on send like Thunderbird will](https://superuser.com/questions/221625/entourage-2008-or-outlook-2003-7-always-bcc-a-specific-address-on-send-like-th) "Entourage 2008 or Outlook 2003/7 - always BCC a specific address on send like Thunderbird will" but I am not able to select bcc the message, only cc the message

I am using Outlook 2013.

Comment: [Create a new Auto BCC rule in Outlook](https://www.ablebits.com/outlook-blind-carbon-copy-bcc-email-addins/new-bcc-rule.php)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Seems like there is only a 7-day free trial. For longer use it's around $30. I would prefer a built in or at least free solution.

Comment: I don't think there is one. In any case why do you need to do this? Every email you send is already in your sent items folder ...

Comment: Wow, that would really suprise me. I would simplify ordering my emails. And I really did not expect it to be much of a trouble

Comment: MS have so far [declined to add this functionality](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other/set-up-auto-bcc-in-outlook-2016/04bb2807-16d4-4641-a48e-19ba3f34ff26)

Comment: You can easily create a VBA macro for this. This macro has to listen to Application.ItemSend event and add the BCC to the item being sent as required.